# Notting but the latest post content keeps on being loaded

Tags: query-posts

Im loading post into a content area via ajax but the latest post is the only one that loads, any one encounter this and manage to fixed it, if so please enlighten me.

```
   <div class="content">    

<?php $args = array('posts_per_page' => 1); query_posts($args);?>
<?php while ( have_posts() ): the_post(); ?>

    <div id="inner">
        <h2 class="title">
            <?php the_title(); ?>
        </h2>
        <?php the_post_thumbnail(array(150, 150, true)); ?>
        <?php the_content(); ?>  
    </div>



      <div class="clear"></div>

      <?php endwhile; ?>
       <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>

    </div>
```

its not my ajax script because I get the same result every time, and yes single.php is present but im not using it in anyway.

The javascript

```
var $mainContent = jQuery(".content"),
            siteUrl = "http://" + top.location.host.toString(),
            url = '';

     jQuery(document).delegate("a[href^='"+siteUrl+"']:not([href*=/wp-admin/]):not([href*=/wp-login.php]):not([href$=/feed/])", "click", function() {
        location.hash = this.pathname;
        return false;
    });



        jQuery(window).bind('hashchange',  function(){
            url = window.location.hash.substring(1); 

            if (!url) {
                return;
            } 

            url = url + " #inner"; 

            $mainContent.slideUp('slow').load(url, function() {
                $mainContent.slideDown('slow');
            });
        });


    jQuery(window).trigger('hashchange');
```

The links to load for ajax

```
<!--Slide -->
            <div id="slider" class="clearfix">

                  <ul id="roundabout" class="clearfix">

                        <?php while (have_posts()): the_post(); ?>

                           <li><a href="<?php the_permalink();?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail(array(150, 150, true));?></a></li>

                        <?php endwhile; ?>

                      </ul>

                    <a id="left" href="#">Left</a>
                    <a id="right" href="#">Right</a>

            </div>
        <!-- End #slider -->
```

Comment: How are you using ajax, could you post your code please? From the above you are querying for the last post and then displaying it.

Comment: that could be the problem, how would i know if I am.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so you're not using AJAX (you didn't share any Javascript here, so I may be confused as to what I'm looking at) but this line:

`<?php $args = array('posts_per_page' => 1); query_posts($args);?>`

indicates you are setting the number of posts to be displayed to just 1, hence the "posts_per_page" value being set to 1. To increase the number of posts display, push that number up to 10 or 20 or whatever you need.

Comment: I only want one post to show at a time, Its a one page website with load post link from a carousel.

Comment: I manage to fix it thanks chris. I change the dashboard reading setting post per page to 1, and removed query post from the main loop. :)